# My module parameters aren't saving . and can't use them in my files

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

```
**mod_cookiACT.xml**
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <extension type="module" version="3.1.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
        <name>Cookie Notifications !</name>
        <author>Engjell</author>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <description>Cookie notifications displaying for the users</description>
        <files>
            <filename>mod_cookienotifications.xml</filename>
            <filename module="mod_cookienotifications">mod_cookienotifications.php</filename>
            <filename>helper.php</filename>
            <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
        </files>
        <config>
            <fields name="param">
                 <fieldset name="basic">
                    <field name="backgroundColor" type="color" default="#eee" format="hex"
                        label="Background Color of the Cookie Notifications!"
                        description="Background Color of the Cookie Notifications!" />
                    <field name="textColor" type="color" default="#eee" format="hex"
                        label="Text color of the Cookie Notifications!"
                        description="Text color of the Cookie Notifications!" />
                    <field name="btnColor" type="color" default="#eee" format="hex"
                        label="Button background color"
                        description="Button background color" />
                 </fieldset>
            </fields>
        </config>
    </extension>
```

**helper.php**

```
class ModCookieNotificationsHelper
{
    private $params = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->params = $this->getParams();
    }
    public function getParams()
    {
        $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_cookieACT');
        $moduleParams = new JRegistry;
        if ($module->params !== '')
        {
            $moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
        }
        return $moduleParams;
    }
    public static function getCookie()
    {
        $helper = new ModCookieNotificationsHelper();
        $backgroundColor = $helper->getParams()->get('backgroundColor');
        $textColor = $helper->getParams()->get('textColor');
        $btnColor = $helper->getParams()->get('btnColor');
        $javascript = "
            <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.0/cookieconsent.min.js'></script>
            <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            window.cookieconsent.initialise({
                'palette': {
                'popup': {
                    'background': '$backgroundColor',
                    'text': '$textcolor'
                },
                'button': {
                    'background': '$btnColor'
                }
                },
                'position': 'top'
            })});
            </script>";
            return $javascript;
    }
}
```

**mod_cookieACT.php**

```
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$cookieNotification = ModCookieNotificationsHelper::getCookie($params);
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_cookieACT');
```

**default.php**

```
<?php 
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die; ?>
<?php  $result = $doc->addScriptDeclaration($cookieNotification); ?>
```

My javascript is working just fine, but i want to change the colors. Mister Lodder helped me with creating my XML files with the helper function to actually give the admin user a choice of colors. the problem is when I'm trying to save after choosing  a color it doesnt work.

Comment: Oh wait, the custom form you made? Is there something I missed in the previous question? Or are you only using Joomla's standard parameters?

Comment: well ''custom'' as in when you edit this module I want the admin user to be able to set the color of his choice. I want to be able to send the colors in my function get Cookie()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters must be within `params` field group. In the manifest file add `name="params"` attribute to `<fields>` element.

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        ...
    </fields>
</config>
```

`getParams()` in the helper and related code is unnecessary and doesn't work anyways. Remove it along with the constructor and `$params` property. Add `$params` argument to `getCookie()` method and use it within the method:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class ModCookieNotificationsHelper
{
    public static function getCookie($params)
    {
        $backgroundColor = 
        $textColor = $params->get('textColor');
        $btnColor = $params->get('btnColor');
        $javascript = "
            <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.0/cookieconsent.min.js'></script>
            <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            window.cookieconsent.initialise({
                'palette': {
                'popup': {
                    'background': '$backgroundColor',
                    'text': '$textColor'
                },
                'button': {
                    'background': '$btnColor'
                }
                },
                'position': 'top'
            })});
            </script>";
            return $javascript;
    }
}
```

You were already passing `$params` to `getCookie()` so this part is fine:

```
$cookieNotification = ModCookieNotificationsHelper::getCookie($params);
```

The issue should be solved by now. I'd like to share some unrelated observations. Given the current functionality of this module, it shouldn't be a module at all. Instead it should be a plugin, since it only adds script to document's head. The module layout is empty. If you do plan on adding something to the layout, the module can remain a module. But it may not need a helper class at all. Scripts can and should be in the layout so they can be overridden, i.e. in such case the scripts inside `getCookie()` would be moved to the layout, rendering helper class useless.

Finally, when building modules make sure their helper class matches the module name. Your module is called `mod_cookieACT` but your helper class is named after `mod_cookienotifications`. If such module exists, this would cause class conflicts. I would also avoid using capital letters in module name and main module file, just in case there's some code in Joomla that expects the names to be lowercase.

Comment: thanks for answering! I'm seeing the form on my module window but when I press save it doesn't still save the colors and I even get a message -->Undefined variable on my function getcookie

Comment: Have you changed `<fields>` to `<fields name="params">` in the manifest file (`mod_cookieACT.xml`)? If so, the values should save properly. Undefined variable is due to a typo in `$textColor` and `$textcolor`. Notice the casing.

Comment: Must be `name="params"`, not `name="param"`.

Comment: you're right! I was able to save it thanks!  not sure if my cookie notifications is working but i'll try thanks!!! If I change it to a plugin it wouldn't be much trouble right?

Comment: I haven't touched the JS code, apart from retrieval of params. The code, as you'll find out does not work. Because the code in `addScriptDeclaration()` must not be wrapped with `<script>` tags. And script files should be added `addScript()` instead or HTMLHelper's `script()` method. The code you currently have could be added using document's `addCustomTag()` method but that's not recommended.

Comment: @engjellbislimi Yes, a plugin would be simpler. Just one function for adding the scripts to the page.

Comment: thank you ! really helped me a lot